# Share Google nest camera with another account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, nest-device-access

I have I Google Nest camera on my Google Account

I have obtained access to the live feed using the [Google Apis](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream?hl=en).

My application lets the user authenticate with oAuth to gain access to the streaming.

Is there a way to share access to the camera to another Google account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To organize and manage your devices in the Google Home app, you can create a home. Then, you can invite home members who will share control of the home and its devices. For example, you can put your grouped living room speakers, office lights, and thermostat into a home, and invite your family to be members of that home. More information in this regard can be found [here](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9155535?hl=en#zippy=%2Cinvite-members-to-a-home).

- You can invite members to your account. Then they will be able to see the camera device in their account. They can try and see if this works.